# Swift PageView a part of lastest image stay in border after Scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipageviewcontroller

When I scroll back in my pageView, a part of the lastest page/image stay in the border right.

How can I fix this ?

This problem does not appear on Iphone 6 Plus & 6S Plus simulator.
On other simulator, it appear when I scroll back (to the left), and if I rescroll to the right the view is correctly placed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by **selecting my view** and in the **Attributes inspector** checking the **Clip Subviews** box in my ContentViewController that contain images.